# How to retain data.table class when piped through dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

I have a data.table object, which I'm piping through few dplyr functions.
When passed through `dplyr::select`, the class of resulting object is data.table + data.frame.
But when I pass it through `dplyr::filter`, class of output is data.frame only.

```
mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)         # "data.table" "data.frame"

mtcars_dt %>% dplyr::select(hp, mpg) %>% class # "data.table" "data.frame"
mtcars_dt %>% dplyr::filter(hp > 100) %>% class # "data.frame"
```

Why does it happen and how do I ensure the data.table class is retained while using `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: If you are using data.table, why can't data.table methods be used i.e. `mtcars_dt[hp>100]` or in a pipe `mtcars_dt %>% .[hp>100]`

Comment: Isn't @akrun suggestion "piping"? He just uses `data.table` syntax instead of `dplyr` functions.

Comment: You can chain with data.table too: `mtcars_dt[, .(hp, mpg)][hp > 100]`

Comment: First, I entirely agree with @akrun and Jaap here (use `data.table` methods!), Still, _if_ you absolutely want to use `dplyr` functions on a `data.table` and retain class `data.table`, you may use `dtplyr::tbl_dt` to "Create A Data Table Tbl". Disclaimer: I have not used the function, I have just noted that it existed. I don't know if you will run into trouble at some point having `class` `"tbl_dt" "tbl"`, in addition to `"data.table" "data.frame"`.

Comment: In addition, please note [the `dtplyr` notes](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr): "dtplyr will always be a bit slower than data.table, because it creates copies of objects rather than mutating in place (that's the dplyr philosophy). Currently, dtplyr is quite a lot slower than bare data.table because the methods aren't quite smart enough.". Thus, better to just stick to `data.table` methods.

Comment: @Henrik Maybe you should post an answer. Fwiw, after I load dtplyr, the OP's code gives the same class vector for both lines.

Answer (score 4):

Originally, I thought it would be necessary to explicitly convert the `data.table` to a "data table `tbl`", using `tbl_dt`, to retain class `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars_dt %>% tbl_dt() %>% dplyr::select(hp, mpg) %>% class
# [1] "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"

mtcars_dt %>% tbl_dt() %>% dplyr::filter(hp > 100) %>% class
# [1] "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"
```

However, as pointed out by Frank in the comments, merely loading `dtplyr` is enough:

```
mtcars_dt %>% dplyr::select(hp, mpg) %>% class
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"

mtcars_dt %>% dplyr::filter(hp > 100) %>% class
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Weird. Or? I posted a [`dtplyr` issue](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/58), so hopefully some `dtplyr` aficionados can shed some light on this.

---

The `.data` argument and **Value** are the same in `?filter` and `?select`, so from this information only it's hard to tell why `.data` of class `data.table` is treated differently in the two functions.

---

After this little excerise, I would still argue that you should stick to `data.table` syntax. In particular, you can chain operations:

```
mtcars_dt[ , .(hp, mpg)][hp > 100]
# or
mtcars_dt[j = .(hp, mpg)][i = hp > 100]
```

Comment: Hi @Ashrith. Just curious: did my answer solve your problem?